# Is there a way to get the last sheet name in Google-sheet scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have got sheets with the names of months and the last one is the current month.
How can I get to point to the current month sheet in Google scripting?
Is there a way to get the last sheet name by  matching the current month in Google sheet scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that last sheet(object) in the spreadsheet you can try

```
const lastSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().pop();
```

and if you want the name of that sheet you can do

```
const lastSheetName = lastSheet.getName();
```

Hope that helps?